# Getting random numbers after a simple math problem. Might be a local variable thing

Tags: c#, types, local-variables

I have a GUI working on the front end. But on the back end I have a little problem with my math. Code is trying to calculate how much time has gone with only starting and ending hours. (There are no info on days). So I think I found the way to calculate the hours spent on paper. But in C# I failed I think because of local variable stuff.

```
float start = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
float end = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);
float hours_spent = end - start;
if (start > end) {
    hours_spent = 24.00f -start + end;
}
```

First part is working correctly but when I give the start bigger than end, it gives me random numbers.

EDIT: When i gave 14.00 as an input and 13.00 as an output i get -76
and for input 14.00 output 12.00 i get -176 and for 18.50 to 10.25 i get -801. It is not random i can see that too my bad on choosing the words. But i dont get it what is wrong

Comment: Can you give an example for start bigger than end and the result you get?

Comment: I doubt that would give "random" numbers; it likely gives the same numbers for the same inputs. Perhaps you can [edit] your question to include what values your are passing, what outputs you are getting, and how those differ from what you are expecting.

Comment: There are several bad practices in this short amount of code, but "randomness" is not one of them. Can you say more clearly what the problem is? Do you have a *question*? You haven't asked a question here.

Comment: Maybe it’s because of your local-settings, when parsing the float. You’re from Turkey?

Comment: Yes i am from Turkey

Comment: What should i use for converting string to a float?

Comment: @süleyman: That's a great question but it is possibly the wrong question to start with; the question I would start with is "why am I parsing to float?" If the quantity is logically a *decimal* value then you should be parsing to *decimal*, and if it is logically a *physical* value then you should be parsing to *double*, and if it is a date or time then you should be parsing to `DateTime`. I don't understand why you are parsing to float at all.

Comment: I would ask you a simple question. If entry time is 13.55 and exit time is 14.05 what should be the expected logical result ? It should be 10 (minutes) or 50 (numeric difference) ?

Comment: To answer your question, you should use `TryParse` to convert a string to a float, because the value in the text box might not be a legal float. Moreover, you should verify that you are using the parsing settings for the correct local; in some places in the world the "decimal place" is `,` and in some places it is `.`, and the parser knows that.

Comment: @Steve I am expecting 10 as minutes but i can see ur point. But without a day how can i get the result on how much time spent without making it double or something and extract from eachother?

Comment: @Eric Lippert I have no idea how i could verify the parsing settings.

Comment: @süleyman: Well today is a great day to learn how to search MSDN for parsing settings then! Hint: you'll want to look at the documentation for `NumberStyles`.

Answer (score 5):

> When i gave 14.00 as an input and 13.00 as an output i get -76

You are parsing in a part of the world where `.` is not the decimal separator but is a common "group" separator. That is, a number like one hundred thousand plus a quarter is written `100.000,25`, and not as it would be in the United States, `100,000.25`.  `Parse` assumes that the string is in the format of the current user's locale unless you tell it otherwise.

Therefore you are parsing the strings into values `1400` and `1300`.  Their difference is `-100`, which is less than 0, so you add 24 to -100 and get -76.

Same for your other case. You have `1850` and to `1025`, subtract them to get `-825`, add `24` and you get `-801`.

There's nothing "random" at all here; **everything is working as expected.**

There is a lesson here: **work backwards**.  You got -76.  How'd that happen? You must have added 24 to something. What added to 24 gives you -76?  -100.  How did we get -100?  And so on.

**Start over**.  You should not be parsing floats in the first place. If this is a decimal quantity then you should be parsing a *decimal*, and if you know that it will always have `.` as the decimal separator, you should say so when you parse it. (Hint: use the version of `TryParse` that takes a `NumberStyles` and set the style correctly.)

If, on the other hand, you know that this is *two integers separated by a period*, then you should not be parsing it as a decimal or a float. You should be parsing an integer, then a period, then an integer.

If this is hours then a period then minutes, then again, you should not be using any of the above. **Use a date and time parser to parse dates and times.**

In short: **use the right tool for the job you actually have to do**.

Other problems with your code:

- Use `TryParse`, not `Parse`, when dealing with user input. You don't know that there is a valid number in there, but `Parse` will crash if it gets bad input.
- Your math is probably wrong.  If someone puts in 100 and 200, do you really want -76 as the output?

Take a step back and ask yourself what the real business process is that you're trying to build here.  **Write that business process down carefully** and then implement that process, not an approximation of it.  Your business process probably does not say "parse a float using the rules of the current locale" but that's the code you wrote.  Write code that means *exactly what you intend it to mean*.

UPDATE: Comments on the question indicate just how deep a hole you've gotten yourself into:

> If entry time is 13.55 and exit time is 14.05 what should be the expected logical result ? It should be 10 (minutes) or 50 (numeric difference) ?
>
> I am expecting 10 as minutes

Then absolutely you should not be parsing as float or decimal! Parsing as float or decimal is obviously **completely wrong** because `1.1` and `1.10` are the *same* value as a number, but *nine minutes different* if it is "hours.minutes", and you can't tell which case you are in by parsing as a number.

Again, you need to stop writing code, erase everything you've written so far, and **start over**.  You're in a hole: stop digging deeper, fill in the hole, and get back to ground level.

You need to figure out *exactly* what format your strings are in, and parse *exactly* that format and *nothing else*.

So, write a specification that poses and then answers questions about what is allowed and what is not.  Are negative values allowed? What if the number of minutes is more than 60?  What if the minutes or hours are missing entirely? And so on.

Once you have a specification, **write test cases that verify the spec**.  Then write an implementation, and run your tests.  The code is more likely to be correct if you write the tests first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to completely ignore providing a didactic answer in favor of trying to sidestep the problem.

Avoid writing your own parsing code.  Instead, replace all your `TextBoxes` with `DateTimePickers` with `Format` set to `Time`.  Then pull out the time by calling the `.Value.TimeOfDay` property.  `TimeOfDay` is a `TimeSpan`, so it supports simple arithmetic.

Warning: Watch out when pulling these results using the provided properties.  For example, 150 minutes can be translated as either 2 `.Hours` and 30 `.Minutes` or to 150 `.TotalMinutes` .